# WebRTC P2P with browser and Android (Flutter) not working although everything seems fine

Tags: node.js, webrtc, kurento

I tried to set up a WebRTC P2P video communication with flutter, a node backend as signaling server and kurento media server.

When I run the app in combination with the Kurento Demo everything works fine but as soon as I try to implement my own backend the video stream doesn't start although the log messages indicate that everything is ok.

Please let me know if more input is required to find a solution.

## Relevant code snippets

### Web Frontend:

```js
call(username) {
    const wrapper = this;
    const remoteVideo = this.videoOutputFactory();

    if (!remoteVideo) {
      console.error('videoOutput not found');
    }

    const options = {
      'remoteVideo': document.getElementById('testVideo'),
      onicecandidate(candidate) {
        console.debug('onicecandidate', candidate);
        wrapper.rpc.onIceCandidate(candidate);
      },
      mediaConstraints: wrapper.remoteMediaConstraints
    };

    console.debug('WebRtcWrapper.call: options', options);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('Creating WebRtcPeer');
      this.webRtcPeer = kurentoUtils.WebRtcPeer.WebRtcPeerSendrecv(options, (error) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error('Error while creating WebRtcPeer', error);
          reject(error);
          return;
        }

        console.log('Generating WebRtcPeer offer');
        this.webRtcPeer.generateOffer((offerError, offerSdp) => {
          if (offerError) {
            console.error('Error while generating WebRtcPeer offer', error);
            reject(error);
            return;
          }

          this.rpc.call(username, offerSdp).then((res) => {
            console.log("Got call answer - Generated-SDPOffer: " + offerSdp);
            if (res.response === 'rejected') {
              console.log('Call rejected by peer');
              reject(res.rejectionMessage);
              return;
            }

            console.log('Processing peer SDP answer', res.sdpAnswer);
            this.webRtcPeer.processAnswer(res.sdpAnswer);
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

### App

```
TestController._()
      : _channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('wss://server.marcostephan.at:443') {
    _peer = jsonrpc.Peer(_channel.cast<String>());

    _peer.registerMethod(
        'rtc.incomingCall', (jsonrpc.Parameters message) async => await _onIncomingCall(message));
    _peer.registerMethod(
        'rtc.offerIceCandidate', (jsonrpc.Parameters message) => _onOfferIceCandidate(message));
    _peer.registerMethod(
        'rtc.startCommunication', (jsonrpc.Parameters message) => _onStartCommunication(message));
    _peer.registerMethod('conn.heartbeat', (jsonrpc.Parameters message) => "");
    _peer.registerFallback((jsonrpc.Parameters params) =>
        print('Unknown request [${params.method}]: ${params.value}'));

    _peer.listen();

    _peer.sendRequest("auth.login", {'username': 'john.doe', 'role': 'actor'});
    _peer.sendNotification("disp.helpMe", {'category': 'spareParts'});
  }

  _onIncomingCall(jsonrpc.Parameters message) async {
    try{

      print('Incoming call from ${message['username'].value}');

      if (this.onStateChange != null) {
        this.onStateChange(SignalingState.CallStateNew);
      }

        await _createPeerConnection();

        RTCSessionDescription s = await _peerConnection
            .createOffer(_constraints);
        _peerConnection.setLocalDescription(s);

        return {
          'from': message['username'].value,
          'callResponse': 'accept',
          'sdpOffer': s.sdp
        };
    }
    catch(e){
      print('TestController._onIncomingCall: ERROR: $e');
    }
  }

  _onOfferIceCandidate(jsonrpc.Parameters message) {
    try{
      var candidateMap = message['candidate'].value;
      print('Received IceCandidate $candidateMap');

      if (_peerConnection != null) {
        RTCIceCandidate candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(candidateMap['candidate'],
            candidateMap['sdpMid'], candidateMap['sdpMLineIndex']);
        _peerConnection.addCandidate(candidate);
      }
    }
    catch(e){
      print('TestController._onOfferIceCandidate: ERROR: $e');
    }
  }

  _onStartCommunication(jsonrpc.Parameters message) {
    try{
      _peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(
          RTCSessionDescription(message['sdpAnswer'].value, 'answer'));
    }
    catch(e){
      print('TestController._onStartCommunication: ERROR: $e');
    }
  }

  _createPeerConnection() async {
    _localStream = await _createStream();
    RTCPeerConnection pc = await createPeerConnection(_iceServers, _config);
    _peerConnection = pc;
    pc.addStream(_localStream);
    pc.onAddStream = (stream) {
      if (this.onRemoteStream != null) this.onRemoteStream(stream);
      //_remoteStreams.add(stream);
    };

    pc.onIceConnectionState = (state) {
      print(
          'TestController._createPeerConnection: onIceConnectionState: $state');
    };

    pc.onIceCandidate = (candidate) {
      _peer.sendNotification("rtc.onIceCandidate", {
        'candidate': {
          'sdpMLineIndex': candidate.sdpMlineIndex,
          'sdpMid': candidate.sdpMid,
          'candidate': candidate.candidate
        }
      });
    };
  }

  Future<MediaStream> _createStream() async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> mediaConstraints = {
      'audio': true,
      'video': {
        'mandatory': {
          'minWidth': '1980',
          'minHeight': '1020',
          'minFrameRate': '30',
        },
        'facingMode': 'environment',
        'optional': [],
      }
    };

    MediaStream stream = await navigator.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints);

    if (this.onLocalStream != null) {
      this.onLocalStream(stream);
    }

    return stream;
  }

  final Map<String, dynamic> _iceServers = {
    'iceServers': [
      {'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'},
    ]
  };

  final Map<String, dynamic> _config = {
    'mandatory': {},
    'optional': [
      {'DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement': true},
    ],
  };

  final Map<String, dynamic> _constraints = {
    'mandatory': {
      'OfferToReceiveAudio': true,
      'OfferToReceiveVideo': true,
    },
    'optional': [],
  };
```

## Logs

### Web Frontend

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/sQ2A1DPc)

### App

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/71UXkFf6)

Comment: Hi, did you come up with a solution for this?

Comment: hey did you get the solution?